# How to have a role in animation of table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

How can I create an animation like in the following link?

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zjYheXX29tSGt2WHg5ckZxOUEtNmpsaEd2YzZXcVh2cld3/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using the below for animate cell from left in tableview delegate method willdisplaycell. Issue is all the cells are animating at a time not one after other, can anyone advice me how can I achieve that?

```
let direction:CGFloat =  -1.0
cell?.layer.opacity = 0.4
cell?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: (cell?.bounds.size.width)! * direction, y: 0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.85, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {
    cell?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    cell?.contentView.layer.opacity = 1.0
}) { _ in
    self.isForExpand = false
}
```

Comment: I think this question could be improved by adding text to describe the animation as best you can. One purpose of SO is to make knowledge searchable for others, and this won't help anyone but you.

Comment: You are going to want to look at Core Animation. The lack of details in your question makes it look like you want someone else to write your code for you which is _not_ what this site is for. Adding in details about what you have tried or asking what technology you should start with will yield you better results

Comment: @theMikeSwan I have update the question notes can you please suggest any solution for that